Trying to get a family of solutions from an undetermined system of differential equations
I am trying to solve an undetermined system of differential equations just to get a family of solutions , I tried writing a code as follows:
`T = (-2*k (A'[r] h'[r]) + D[(h[r] A[r]), r] k'[r])/(A[r] h[r] k[r])
G = FullSimplify[D[T, r]]/T
DSolve[{T + 1/(A[r] h[r] k[r])*A'[r]*D[(h[r] k[r]), r] + 
A[r]*D[(D[(h[r] k[r]), r]), r] + 
D[(h[r] k[r]), r]/(2*h[r] k[r])*G == 0, 
T + 1/(A[r] h[r] k[r]) h'[r]*D[(k[r] A[r]), r] + 
h[r]*D[(D[(A[r] k[r]), r]), r] + 
D[(A[r] k[r]), r]/(2*A[r] k[r])*G == 0}, {A[r], h[r], k[r]}, r]`

Can someone help me modify the code to get a family of solutions
